# Comma with preposition phrases

Tags: prepositional-phrases, commas

> 1. The man, from the country, is just one of my close friends.
> 2. The man from the country is just one of my close friends.

I'm curious to know whether there are any subtle differences in meaning or in use. 
I suspect number 2 could be used when I want to clarify who's the man I'm referring to among the men we've already known or talked about, but if it wouldn't be confusing who's the man I'm indicating, then, I think I don't need to add commas. I mean if there was the only man who we have just talked about, there's no need to restrict the information of the man by adding "from the country" without commas, but I'm not sure whether my understanding is getting to the point, and could you please bring out or make up some sentences in which preposition phrases starting with "of" can be used as examples for teaching this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.*The man, from the country, is just one of my close friends.*
>
> 2.*The man from the country is just one of my close friends.*

They are both grammatically possible.

In 1. the PP "from the country" is a supplement, not a modifier of "man". But it doesn't make much sense. Why would you want to make the PP non-defining?

In 2. the PP does modify "man" and makes much more sense. You clearly have several close friends and the man from the country is just one of them.

Comment: Then, what is "from the country" modifying in number 1? And why don't we think of "from the country" as the shortened form of "being from the country" or "who is from the country" in number 1?

Comment: And what about this sentence? **The girl, in front of the door, is my younger sister** Is this sentence also incorrect with commas?

Comment: Are there not any sentences in which a prepositional phrase can modify a noun as in number 1? If possible, could you bring up some sentences?

Comment: @SIS Supplements are not modifiers, so the PP in 1. doesn't modify anything. It's not part of the NP. But the PP in 2. is a modifier of the noun "man".

Comment: @SIS Your "girl" example is grammatically possible, but odd. Why would you want to make a defining phrase a supplement? That makes no sense. Ditch the commas.

Comment: Then, do you think these sentences sound unnatural as well? 1. Ms. Zither, in a great hurry, forgot to lock the classroom door and close the windows. 2. The boy's mother, at a loss to know why he was crying, tried to console him 3. The young man, madly in love with his employer's daughter, is afraid to ask her to marry him.

Comment: @SIS Those are predicative adjuncts, so different considerations apply.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is not subtle, number 1 is incorrect. You must not separate "from the country" from "the man" as they are related to each other, none of them being a clause in itself (having a verb).

Therefore, 2. is correct.

You can make 1. correct like this:

> 1. The man, **who is** from the country, is just one of my close friends.

or (suggested by @user45266; with slightly different meaning):

> 1. The man, **being** from the country, is just one of my close friends.

Comment: One could replace "who is" with "being" as well (largely depending on context).

Comment: Then, what is "from the country" modifying in number 1? And why don't we think of "from the country" as the shortened form of "being from the country" or "who is from the country" in number 1?

Comment: And what about this sentence? **The girl, in front of the door, is my younger sister** Is this sentence also incorrect with commas?

Comment: The new sentence (with the girl) also sounds incorrect, with the same explanation.

Comment: Words and clauses cannot be treated in the same way in a sentence. That is why using or not using a verb changes the structure and the rules (slightly).

Comment: I don't understand this: "Aren't there any..."

Comment: Are there not any sentences in which a prepositional phrase can modify a noun as in number 1? If possible, could you bring up some sentences?

Comment: I am not aware of such cases.

Comment: Then, do you think these sentences sound unnatural as well? 1. Ms. Zither, in a great hurry, forgot to lock the classroom door and close the windows. 2. The boy's mother, at a loss to know why he was crying, tried to console him 3. The young man, madly in love with his employer's daughter, is afraid to ask her to marry him.

Comment: Sentences are not to be analyzed by the commas in the text. The new sentences you provided sound natural, but they do not follow the same pattern as the original question.